# WMIC Path <what>? WMIC Class <what>?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wmi, wmic

There are all sorts of commands that `WMIC` accepts, such as

```
WMIC Path Win32_Battery
WMIC Path Win32_Processor
WMIC Class Win32_Battery
WMIC Class ComputerSystem
```

et cetera.

Is there any way to **list** all of these potential "path"s and "class"es, etc. from the command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you list them here, you are asking for a list of WMI object classes (primarily from the Win32 section); the "Path" could be that, that plus sub-node, that plus sub-node plus value, etc. [See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390350(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Conceptually similar to a Uniform Resource Locator (URL), a WMI object path is a string that uniquely identifies the namespace on a server, a class within a namespace, or instances of a class

Which classes are available will depend on the version of Windows (amongst other things, since I believe custom WMI classes can be registered within the WMI system), so you can't assume that all classes will be available for all versions of Windows.

Having said that:

There's no way I know of to list them from the stock command-line.  With [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) you can get the entire list of Win32 WMI classes by using the following command:

`Get-WMIObject -List| Where{$_.name -match "^Win32_"} | Sort Name | Format-Table Name`

You should also be able to use Windows scripting (ie: VBScript) to get it as well.

Win32 is one of about 10 different sections of classes.

You can get the current WMI section/class/method/property [lists from MS' MSDN pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394554(v=VS.85).aspx).

Here is a list of (most of) the Win32 WMI classes:

- Win32_1394Controller
- Win32_1394ControllerDevice
- Win32_AccountSID
- Win32_ActionCheck
- Win32_ActiveRoute
- Win32_AllocatedResource
- Win32_ApplicationCommandLine
- Win32_ApplicationService
- Win32_AssociatedBattery
- Win32_AssociatedProcessorMemory
- Win32_AutochkSetting
- Win32_BaseBoard
- Win32_Battery
- Win32_Binary
- Win32_BindImageAction
- Win32_BIOS
- Win32_BootConfiguration
- Win32_Bus Win32_CacheMemory
- Win32_CDROMDrive
- Win32_CheckCheck
- Win32_CIMLogicalDeviceCIMDataFile
- Win32_ClassicCOMApplicationClasses
- Win32_ClassicCOMClass
- Win32_ClassicCOMClassSetting
- Win32_ClassicCOMClassSettings
- Win32_ClassInforAction
- Win32_ClientApplicationSetting
- Win32_CodecFile
- Win32_COMApplicationSettings
- Win32_COMClassAutoEmulator
- Win32_ComClassEmulator
- Win32_CommandLineAccess
- Win32_ComponentCategory
- Win32_ComputerSystem
- Win32_ComputerSystemProcessor
- Win32_ComputerSystemProduct
- Win32_ComputerSystemWindowsProductActivationSetting
- Win32_Condition
- Win32_ConnectionShare
- Win32_ControllerHastHub
- Win32_CreateFolderAction
- Win32_CurrentProbe
- Win32_DCOMApplication
- Win32_DCOMApplicationAccessAllowedSetting
- Win32_DCOMApplicationLaunchAllowedSetting
- Win32_DCOMApplicationSetting
- Win32_DependentService
- Win32_Desktop
- Win32_DesktopMonitor
- Win32_DeviceBus
- Win32_DeviceMemoryAddress
- Win32_Directory
- Win32_DirectorySpecification
- Win32_DiskDrive
- Win32_DiskDrivePhysicalMedia
- Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition
- Win32_DiskPartition
- Win32_DiskQuota
- Win32_DisplayConfiguration
- Win32_DisplayControllerConfiguration
- Win32_DMAChanner
- Win32_DriverForDevice
- Win32_DriverVXD
- Win32_DuplicateFileAction
- Win32_Environment
- Win32_EnvironmentSpecification
- Win32_ExtensionInfoAction
- Win32_Fan
- Win32_FileSpecification
- Win32_FloppyController
- Win32_FloppyDrive
- Win32_FontInfoAction
- Win32_Group
- Win32_GroupDomain
- Win32_GroupUser
- Win32_HeatPipe
- Win32_IDEController
- Win32_IDEControllerDevice
- Win32_ImplementedCategory
- Win32_InfraredDevice
- Win32_IniFileSpecification
- Win32_InstalledSoftwareElement
- Win32_IP4PersistedRouteTable
- Win32_IP4RouteTable
- Win32_IRQResource
- Win32_Keyboard
- Win32_LaunchCondition
- Win32_LoadOrderGroup
- Win32_LoadOrderGroupServiceDependencies
- Win32_LoadOrderGroupServiceMembers
- Win32_LocalTime
- Win32_LoggedOnUser
- Win32_LogicalDisk
- Win32_LogicalDiskRootDirectory
- Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition
- Win32_LogicalFileAccess
- Win32_LogicalFileAuditing
- Win32_LogicalFileGroup
- Win32_LogicalFileOwner
- Win32_LogicalFileSecuritySetting
- Win32_LogicalMemoryConfiguration
- Win32_LogicalProgramGroup
- Win32_LogicalProgramGroupDirectory
- Win32_LogicalProgramGroupItem
- Win32_LogicalProgramGroupItemDataFile
- Win32_LogicalShareAccess
- Win32_LogicalShareAuditing
- Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting
- Win32_LogonSession
- Win32_LogonSessionMappedDisk
- Win32_MappedLogicalDisk
- Win32_MemoryArray
- Win32_MemoryArrayLocation
- Win32_MemoryDevice
- Win32_MemoryDeviceArray
- Win32_MemoryDeviceLocation
- Win32_MIMEInfoAction
- Win32_MotherboardDevice
- Win32_MoveFileAction
- Win32_NamedJobObject
- Win32_NamedJobObjectActgInfo
- Win32_NamedJobObjectLimit
- Win32_NamedJobObjectLimitSetting
- Win32_NamedJobObjectProcess
- Win32_NamedJobObjectSecLimit
- Win32_NamedJobObjectSecLimitSetting
- Win32_NamedJobObjectStatistics
- Win32_NetworkAdapter
- Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
- Win32_NetworkAdapterSetting
- Win32_NetworkClient
- Win32_NetworkConnection
- Win32_NetworkLoginProfile
- Win32_NetworkProtocol
- Win32_NTDomain
- Win32_NTEventlogFile
- Win32_NTLogEvent
- Win32_NTLogEventComputer
- Win32_NTLogEvnetLog
- Win32_NTLogEventUser
- Win32_ODBCAttribute
- Win32_ODBCDataSourceAttribute
- Win32_ODBCDataSourceSpecification
- Win32_ODBCDriverAttribute
- Win32_ODBCDriverSoftwareElement
- Win32_ODBCDriverSpecification
- Win32_ODBCSourceAttribute
- Win32_ODBCTranslatorSpecification
- Win32_OnBoardDevice
- Win32_OperatingSystem
- Win32_OperatingSystemAutochkSetting
- Win32_OperatingSystemQFE
- Win32_OSRecoveryConfiguración
- Win32_PageFile
- Win32_PageFileElementSetting
- Win32_PageFileSetting
- Win32_PageFileUsage
- Win32_ParallelPort
- Win32_Patch
- Win32_PatchFile
- Win32_PatchPackage
- Win32_PCMCIAControler
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASP_ActiveServerPages
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_114322_ASPNETAppsv114322
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_114322_ASPNETv114322
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_2040607_ASPNETAppsv2040607
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_2040607_ASPNETv2040607
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNET
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_aspnet_state_ASPNETStateService
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_ContentFilter_IndexingServiceFilter
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_ContentIndex_IndexingService
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_DTSPipeline_SQLServerDTSPipeline
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_Fax_FaxServices
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_InetInfo_InternetInformationServicesGlobal
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_ISAPISearch_HttpIndexingService
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_MSDTC_DistributedTransactionCoordinator
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETCLRData_NETCLRData
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETCLRNetworking_NETCLRNetworking
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETDataProviderforOracle_NETCLRData
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETDataProviderforSqlServer_NETDataProviderforSqlServer
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRExceptions
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRInterop
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRJit
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRLoading
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRLocksAndThreads
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRRemoting
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NETFramework_NETCLRSecurity
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_NTFSDRV_ControladordealmacenamientoNTFSdeSMTP
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_Outlook_Outlook
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfNet_Browser
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfNet_Redirector
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfNet_Server
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfNet_ServerWorkQueues
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Cache
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Objects
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_PagingFile
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_FullImage_Costly
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Image_Costly
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_JobObject
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_JobObjectDetails
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_ProcessAddressSpace_Costly
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Thread
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_ThreadDetails_Costly
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_RemoteAccess_RASPort
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_RemoteAccess_RASTotal
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_RSVP_RSVPInterfaces
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_RSVP_RSVPService
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_Spooler_PrintQueue
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_TapiSrv_Telephony
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_ICMP
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_IP
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NBTConnection
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_TCP
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_UDP
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_TermService_TerminalServices
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_TermService_TerminalServicesSession
- Win32_PerfFormattedData_W3SVC_WebService
- Win32_PerfRawData_ASP_ActiveServerPages
- Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_114322_ASPNETAppsv114322
- Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_114322_ASPNETv114322
- Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_2040607_ASPNETAppsv2040607
- Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_2040607_ASPNETv2040607
- Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNET
- Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications
- Win32_PerfRawData_aspnet_state_ASPNETStateService
- Win32_PerfRawData_ContentFilter_IndexingServiceFilter
- Win32_PerfRawData_ContentIndex_IndexingService
- Win32_PerfRawData_DTSPipeline_SQLServerDTSPipeline
- Win32_PerfRawData_Fax_FaxServices
- Win32_PerfRawData_InetInfo_InternetInformationServicesGlobal
- Win32_PerfRawData_ISAPISearch_HttpIndexingService
- Win32_PerfRawData_MSDTC_DistributedTransactionCoordinator
- Win32_PerfRawData_NETCLRData_NETCLRData
- Win32_PerfRawData_NETCLRNetworking_NETCLRNetworking
- Win32_PerfRawData_NETDataProviderforOracle_NETCLRData
- Win32_PerfRawData_NETDataProviderforSqlServer_NETDataProviderforSqlServer
- Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRExceptions
- Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRInterop
- Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRJit
- Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRLoading
- Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRLocksAndThreads
- Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRMemory
- Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRRemoting
- Win32_PerfRawData_NETFramework_NETCLRSecurity
- Win32_PerfRawData_NTFSDRV_ControladordealmacenamientoNTFSdeSMTP
- Win32_PerfRawData_Outlook_Outlook
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_PhysicalDisk
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfNet_Browser
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfNet_Redirector
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfNet_Server
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfNet_ServerWorkQueues
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Cache
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Memory
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Objects
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_PagingFile
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_Processor
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfOS_System
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_FullImage_Costly
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Image_Costly
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_JobObject
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_JobObjectDetails
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_ProcessAddressSpace_Costly
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Thread
- Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_ThreadDetails_Costly
- Win32_PerfRawData_RemoteAccess_RASPort
- Win32_PerfRawData_RemoteAccess_RASTotal
- Win32_PerfRawData_RSVP_RSVPInterfaces
- Win32_PerfRawData_RSVP_RSVPService
- Win32_PerfRawData_Spooler_PrintQueue
- Win32_PerfRawData_TapiSrv_Telephony
- Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_ICMP
- Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_IP
- Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NBTConnection
- Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface
- Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_TCP
- Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_UDP
- Win32_PerfRawData_TermService_TerminalServices
- Win32_PerfRawData_TermService_TerminalServicesSession
- Win32_PerfRawData_W3SVC_WebService
- Win32_PhysicalMedia
- Win32_PhysicalMemory
- Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray
- Win32_PhysicalMemoryLocation
- Win32_PingStatus
- Win32_PNPAllocatedResource
- Win32_PnPDevice
- Win32_PnPEntity
- Win32_PnPSignedDriver
- Win32_PnPSignedDriverCIMDataFile
- Win32_PointingDevice
- Win32_PortableBattery
- Win32_PortConnector
- Win32_PortResource
- Win32_POTSModem
- Win32_POTSModemToSerialPort
- Win32_Printer
- Win32_PrinterConfiguration
- Win32_PrinterController
- Win32_PrinterDriver
- Win32_PrinterDriverDll
- Win32_PrinterSetting
- Win32_PrinterShare
- Win32_PrintJob
- Win32_Process
- Win32_Processor
- Win32_Product
- Win32_ProductCheck
- Win32_ProductResource
- Win32_ProductSoftwareFeatures
- Win32_ProgIDSpecification
- Win32_ProgramGroup
- Win32_ProgramGroupContents
- Win32_Property
- Win32_ProtocolBinding
- Win32_Proxy
- Win32_PublishComponentAction
- Win32_QuickFixEngineering
- Win32_QuotaSetting
- Win32_Refrigeration
- Win32_Registry
- Win32_RegistryAction
- Win32_RemoveFileAction
- Win32_RemoveIniAction
- Win32_ReserveCost
- Win32_ScheduledJob
- Win32_SCSIController
- Win32_SCSIControllerDevice
- Win32_SecuritySettingOfLogicalFile
- Win32_SecuritySettingOfLogicalShare
- Win32_SelfRegModuleAction
- Win32_SerialPort
- Win32_SerialPortConfiguration
- Win32_SerialPortSetting
- Win32_ServerConnection
- Win32_ServerSession
- Win32_Service
- Win32_ServiceControl
- Win32_ServiceSpecification
- Win32_ServiceSpecificationService
- Win32_SessionConnection
- Win32_SessionProcess
- Win32_Share
- Win32_ShareToDirectory
- Win32_ShortcutAction
- Win32_ShortcutFile
- Win32_ShortcutSAP
- Win32_SID
- Win32_SoftwareElement
- Win32_SoftwareElementAction
- Win32_SoftwareElementCheck
- Win32_SoftwareElementCondition
- Win32_SoftwareElementResource
- Win32_SoftwareFeature
- Win32_SoftwareFeatureAction
- Win32_SoftwareFeatureCheck
- Win32_SoftwareFeatureParent
- Win32_SoftwareFeatureSoftwareElements
- Win32_SoundDevice
- Win32_StartupCommand
- Win32_SubDirectory
- Win32_SystemAccount
- Win32_SystemBIOS
- Win32_SystemBootConfiguration
- Win32_SystemDesktop
- Win32_SystemDevices
- Win32_SystemDriver
- Win32_SystemDriverPNPEntity
- Win32_SystemEnclosure
- Win32_SystemLoadOrderGroups
- Win32_SystemLogicalMemoryConfiguration
- Win32_SystemNetworkConnections
- Win32_SystemOperatingSystem
- Win32_SystemPartitions
- Win32_SystemProcesses
- Win32_SystemProgramGroups
- Win32_SystemResources
- Win32_SystemServices
- Win32_SystemSlot
- Win32_SystemSystemDriver
- Win32_SystemTimeZone
- Win32_SystemUsers
- Win32_TapeDrive
- Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort
- Win32_TemperatureProbe
- Win32_Terminal
- Win32_TerminalService
- Win32_TerminalServiceSetting
- Win32_TerminalServiceToSetting
- Win32_TerminalTerminalSetting
- Win32_Thread
- Win32_TimeZone
- Win32_TSAccount
- Win32_TSClientSetting
- Win32_TSEnvironmentSetting
- Win32_TSGeneralSetting
- Win32_TSLogonSetting
- Win32_TSNetworkAdapterListSetting
- Win32_TSNetworkAdapterSetting
- Win32_TSPermissionsSetting
- Win32_TSRemoteControlSetting
- Win32_TSSessionDirectory
- Win32_TSSessionDirectorySetting
- Win32_TSSessionSetting
- Win32_TypeLibraryAction
- Win32_UninterruptiblePowerSupply
- Win32_USBController
- Win32_USBControllerDevice
- Win32_USBHub
- Win32_UserAccount
- Win32_UserDesktop
- Win32_UserInDomain
- Win32_UTCTime
- Win32_VideoController
- Win32_VideoSettings
- Win32_VoltageProbe
- Win32_VolumeQuotaSetting
- Win32_WindowsProductActivation
- Win32_WMIElementSetting
- Win32_WMISetting

Comment: Don't forget that there are also aliases that map to these classes. Try the cmd `wmic alias list brief` for a listing of them on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are some [WMI providers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmi-providers), which provide with lots of classes. It's possible to discover WMI classes through WMI as mentioned in the other answer. The list of classes is not that hard-coded within `wmic`, it can be extended dynamically via [registering custom providers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/registering-a-provider).

Probably, what you wanted to ask was "what can I do with WMI and `wmic`". There are a lot of possibilities: managing OS settings, devices, file system. (Although you cannot create a file with data, but you can rename or delete a file.) A solution may involve setting properties, invoking methods and working with associations. To find out how to accomplish something with WMI, try searching in internet for "wmi do something". Another options is to look for related classes in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

These are the wmi class aliases wmic has (including "alias", which is "Msft_CliAlias" under the ROOT\Cli namespace), which are likely to be the wmi classes you use the most (aside from win32_userprofile).  I sorted them in an editor.  You can always use get-wmiobject or get-ciminstance in powershell instead with far more options ("get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem").

```
wmic alias get friendlyname,target

FriendlyName         Target
Alias                Select * from Msft_CliAlias
BIOS                 Select * from Win32_BIOS
BaseBoard            Select * from Win32_BaseBoard
BootConfig           Select * from Win32_BootConfiguration
CDROM                Select * from Win32_CDROMDrive
CPU                  Select * from WIN32_PROCESSOR
CSProduct            Select * from Win32_ComputerSystemProduct
ComputerSystem       Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem
DCOMAPP              Select * from WIN32_DCOMApplication
DESKTOP              Select * from WIN32_DESKTOP
DMAChannel           Select * from Win32_DMAChannel
DataFile             Select * from CIM_DataFile
DesktopMonitor       Select * from WIN32_DESKTOPMONITOR
DeviceMemoryAddress  Select * from Win32_DeviceMemoryAddress
DiskDrive            Select * from Win32_DiskDrive
DiskQuota            Select * from Win32_DiskQuota
Environment          Select * from Win32_Environment
FSDir                Select * from Win32_Directory
Group                Select * from Win32_Group
IDECONTROLLER        Select * from Win32_IDEController
IRQ                  Select * from Win32_IRQResource
Job                  Select * from Win32_ScheduledJob
LOGON                Select * from Win32_LogonSession
LoadOrder            Select * from Win32_LoadOrderGroup
LogicalDisk          Select * from Win32_LogicalDisk
MEMCACHE             Select * from WIN32_CACHEMEMORY
MemPhysical          Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray
MemoryChip           Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory
NIC                  Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter
NICConfig            Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
NTDOMAIN             Select * from Win32_NTDomain
NTEvent              Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent
NTEventLog           Select * from Win32_NTEventlogFile
NetClient            Select * from WIN32_NetworkClient
NetLogin             Select * from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile
NetProtocol          Select * from Win32_NetworkProtocol
NetUse               Select * from Win32_NetworkConnection
OS                   Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem
OnBoardDevice        Select * from Win32_OnBoardDevice
PageFile             Select * from Win32_PageFileUsage
PageFileSet          Select * from Win32_PageFileSetting
Partition            Select * from Win32_DiskPartition
Port                 Select * from Win32_PortResource
PortConnector        Select * from Win32_PortConnector
PrintJob             Select * from Win32_PrintJob
Printer              Select * from Win32_Printer
PrinterConfig        Select * from Win32_PrinterConfiguration
Process              Select * from Win32_Process
Product              Select * from Win32_Product
QFE                  Select * from Win32_QuickFixEngineering
QuotaSetting         Select * from Win32_QuotaSetting
RDAccount            Select * from Win32_TSAccount
RDNIC                Select * from Win32_TSNetworkAdapterSetting
RDPermissions        Select * from Win32_TSPermissionsSetting
RDToggle             Select * from Win32_TerminalServiceSetting
RecoverOS            Select * from Win32_OSRecoveryConfiguration
Registry             Select * from Win32_Registry
SCSICONTROLLER       Select * from Win32_SCSIController
Server               Select * from Win32_PerfRawData_PerfNet_Server
Service              Select * from Win32_Service
ShadowCopy           Select * from Win32_ShadowCopy
ShadowStorage        Select * from Win32_ShadowStorage
Share                Select * from Win32_Share
SoftwareElement      Select * from Win32_SoftwareElement
SoftwareFeature      Select * from Win32_SoftwareFeature
SoundDev             Select * from WIN32_SoundDevice
Startup              Select * from Win32_StartupCommand
SysAccount           Select * from Win32_SystemAccount
SysDriver            Select * from Win32_SystemDriver
SystemEnclosure      Select * from Win32_SystemEnclosure
SystemSlot           Select * from Win32_SystemSlot
TapeDrive            Select * from Win32_TapeDrive
Temperature          Select * from Win32_TemperatureProbe
TimeZone             Select * from Win32_TimeZone
UPS                  Select * from Win32_UninterruptiblePowerSupply
UserAccount          Select * from Win32_UserAccount
Voltage              Select * from Win32_VoltageProbe
Volume               Select * from Win32_Volume
VolumeQuotaSetting   Select * from Win32_VolumeQuotaSetting
VolumeUserQuota      Select * from Win32_VolumeUserQuota
WMISet               Select * from Win32_WMISetting
```

Different namespace for the top three, and the bottom one is gone.  You need to be admin for the shadow ones.  I would use get-package over win32_product.

```
get-wmiobject -n Root\CIMV2\TerminalServices Win32_TerminalServiceSetting
get-wmiobject -n Root\CIMV2\TerminalServices Win32_TSAccount
get-wmiobject -n Root\CIMV2\TerminalServices Win32_TSPermissionsSetting

get-wmiobject Win32_UninterruptiblePowerSupply # Invalid class without a hardware ups?
```